# Symmetry of (the Partial Derivative of) a Multivariate Logistic Function

Tags: functions, symmetry

Fix $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Let 
\begin{equation}
H(\mathbb{w}) := \frac{1}{1+e^{-\sum_1^Nw_i}},\quad (\mathbb{w}\in\mathbb{R}^N).
\end{equation}
I am interested in the symmetries of its partial derivative (say, wrt $w_1$):
\begin{equation}
h(\mathbb{w}) := \frac{\partial}{\partial w_1} H(\mathbb{w}) = \frac{e^{-\sum_1^Nw_i}}{\left(1+e^{-\sum_1^Nw_i} \right)^2}.
\end{equation}
Specifically, I am interested in these symmetries when $N>1$. When $N=1$, I know that $h(\cdot)$ is symmetric and unimodal about $w=0$, i.e. $$ h(w) = h(-w) \ \forall \, w\in\mathbb{R}. $$

I am having trouble thinking about the analogous symmetries for $N\geq 2$, and would appreciate any help in this regard.